# Service fabric stateful service partitioned - well distributed

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Imagine we want to have a stateful service partitioned by range of points,
with the goal of sorting each partition by points (in general, we want to divide the sort task among partitions). We would like to have users well distributed among partitions.
The ideal would be to change the range of each partition while users' points change. But it is not possible, because we cannot change the range of a partition dynamically.

One idea would be to have a single stateful service which would manage the ranges of points and would use a map to tell other services which partition should be requested for specific points. But this may mean lots of accesses to this new service, which may overload the service.

Are there any better ideas?

Edit 1:

Goal 1: To have rankings sorted by sorted-blocks (partitions), which would be aggregated by another service.

Goal 2: To provide a provisional position for a given amount of points.

Comment: So this is points like as in earned points in a game? And you want the highest points ones in a single partition? I'm not sure that would work well, as the highest points ones are also likely to be the highest users, so grouping them together seems counterproductive in terms of load balancing

Comment: @EricLizotte Yes, it is like earned points in a game. The highscore is not obtained directly from this service. The complete score table (not only the top users) would be calculated using this partitioned service but provided in another way. The partitioned service will only be accessed to (1) save updated user points and (2) to get the provisional position for specific amount of points.

Comment: I see what you are getting at now, you'd like the partitions to be by score range so that its easier to query against. It would make more sense to have the scores persisted to a sql table that has the user id + score as the only columns with both indexed, and have the servers query + update that. The primary use for partitions is for load spread and scaling, rather than grouping. I don't see any architectural benefit from having the partitions be based on score.
Trying to partition on score would actually slow performance, as users would perpetually be moving from partition to partition.

Comment: The other way, if you're determined to do it this way is to pre-decide your number of partitions, but rather than having them be by actual score #, its by percentage of maximum score. so with 10 partitions it would be top score to 91%, 90% to 81, etc. The compute cost of moving users partition to partition as that changes would be heavy.

Comment: Otherwise you could only really take what you think to be a reasonable grouping of scores, make your initial set with the partition bands that wide and have the score updates flow through another service that would add the next higher group of scores as a new partition. I still think this is an anti-pattern for partitioning though.

Comment: @EricLizotte Thanks for the hints. The possibilities will be analysed and tested. If an interesting decision is taken, I will share.

Comment: It was decided to skip the partitioning in this case. The sort will be handled in a single stateful service.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you partition the service by userid. For example, take modulo partitioncount of userid to determine the partition index.
This way a user can always be found in a predictable partition, and your users will be distributed well (provided you have many more users than partitions).

You can use a [pub/sub mechanism](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceFabric.PubSubActors/) to publish changing scores to a different (stateless) service, to hold a view of current highscores.

Comment: I just updated the question with the final goals. Partitioning the service by user ID would not fit to my solution.